# Sigmoidoscopy is the minimally invasive medical examination of the large intestine from the rectum "through to" the nearest part of the colon

Tags: meaning-in-context

How come it's "through to" instead of "to" in "[sigmoidoscopy is the minimally invasive medical examination of the large intestine from the rectum through to the nearest part of the colon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoidoscopy)"? Do they mean the same thing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about a journey or path we can use 'through' before 'to' if we wish to emphasise that the route is simple and direct. I might say 'the dog ran in the front door and then through to the kitchen at the back of the house' if the route was direct. I don't want a woodpecker to peck at my ear because it might get too excited and go though to my brain.

You can see that the colon is joined to the sigmoid colon and the first part of that (coming via the colon) is the 'nearest part of the colon'.

You can say, similarly, that you enter a tunnel and go through to the other end.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I just have one more question: Can one say "the dog ran at the front door" instead of "the dog run in the front door"? Thank you so very much once again!

Comment: "Ran at" would mean that the dog ran toward the door, maybe hitting it, but not going through it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!